# Green function - i need same HELP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have this problem:

$Ly=-y''-y$

And the conditions:  $y(0)=y(1)=0$

I started to solve the problem as follows:

The Green's function operator is defined as the linear solution

$-g''(x)-g(x)=\delta(x-s)$

If $x\neq s$ the delta function it's null, and the general solution is:

$g(x,s)=C_1 \cos(x)+ C_2 \sin(x)$

For$x<s$ the boundary condition $x=0$ implies that:

$G(0,s)=C_1 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad C_1=0$

The equation $G(1,s)$ is ignored because $x\neq s$ if $x<s$ and $s\neq1$

For $x>s$ the boundary condition in $x=1$ implies:

$G(1,s)=C_3\cos(1)+C_4\sin(1)=0$

In summary, the result so far is

$G(x,s)=\begin{cases} C_2 \sin(x) & x<s \\ C_3 \cos(x)+C_4 \sin(x) & s<x\end{cases}$

My problem is from here to get the solution I have in my book is:

$G(x, s)=\frac{1}{\sin(1)}\begin{cases}\sin(x)\sin(1-s) & 0\leq x\leq s \\ \sin(1-x)\sin(s) & s\leq x\leq 1 \end{cases}$

thanks for All and Any HELP

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce the discontinuity conditions for the Green function. As you already shown, the Green function is

$$
g(x,s) = \begin{cases} c_1 \sin(x) & 0 < x < s < 1 \\ c_2 \sin(x-1) & 0 < s < x < 1\end{cases}
$$

where I've changed the form of the second solution to simplify the algebra.

Now, [Green function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Green.27s_functions_for_solving_inhomogeneous_boundary_value_problems) is continuous and has a jump of magnitude $\frac{1}{p(s)}$ in its derivative at the point $x=s$. Using this information, we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to s^+} g(x,s) - \lim_{x \to s^-} g(x,s) &= 0 = c_2 \sin(s-1) - c_1 \sin(s)\\
\lim_{x \to s^+} g'(x,s) - \lim_{x \to s^-} g'(x,s) &= -1 = c_2 \cos(s-1) - c_1 \cos(s)
\end{align}

or, in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -\sin(s) & \sin(s-1) \\ - \cos(s) & \cos(s-1)\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{\sin(1)}\begin{pmatrix} \sin(s-1) \\ \sin(s) \end{pmatrix}
$$

and then
$$
g(x,s) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(1-s)}{\sin(1)} & 0 < x < s < 1 \\ \\ \frac{\sin(1-x) \sin(s)}{\sin(1)} & 0 < s < x < 1\end{cases}
$$